# React-Intersection-Observer running into infintite loop giving "Maximum update depth exceeded." in nextjs 14 app directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-intersection-observer

my nextjs 14 app gives me the error "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops." only when i use this library.

my code:

```
 "use client"
 import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";
 import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
 import { useEffect } from "react";

 interface Props{
    dark: boolean;
 }
 export const LoadMore = async ({dark}: Props) => {

   const { ref, inView } = useInView({
     threshold: 0
   })
 
   const router = useRouter();

   useEffect(() => {
     if(inView)
       router.push(`?page=${2}`, { scroll: false});
   }, [inView])
 
return (
 <>
 <div 
 // This line is causing the trouble when i assign the ref 
 ref={ref}
 className={`${!dark ? "lds-ellipsis" : "lds-ellipsis dark"} `}><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
 </>
)
}
```

how to fix this issue

i tried using the useCallBack hook but it didn't work as well.
How can i fix this issue so that the application does not break